# UE4 Drag and Drop: Place PaperCharacter Over Image Widget

Tags: 2d, unreal-4, blueprints

I'm working on adding drag and drop functionality to my game. I have it working with the exception of I can't get what I'm dropping to be placed where it was dropped. I've tried a number of different things but I can't seem to get it to work.

The image shows my OnDrop with some leftovers of things I have been trying. And when I adjust the MakeTransform manually, a change of 1.0 seems to move the character much more than 1 pixel. The item I am creating in the OnDrop is a PaperCharacter.
[image]

Here is an image from part of the level showing the result. The white blocks circled in red are UMG images so I can eventually adjust them to look better and change dynamically as the player is dragging. The player can only drop the item over one of there squares. This functionality works. But no matter which square I drop over the item always gets placed at the point circled in green or nowhere to be seen in the viewport. This is a 2d game so everything has to be in the viewport to be seen. The white squares are attached to a PaperSpriteActor. Not sure if that matters or not.
[image]

What I need to have happen is when the player drops the item above one of the squares, the PaperCharacter must be dropped right in the middle of that square. How do I go about making that happen?

***EDIT***

Another observation, if I manually set the MakeTransform location to 0, 0, 0 and drop the item on the same white square multiple times, the item is dropped in a slightly different spot each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a work around to manually setting the location of the spawned item. So I can now manually set the location of the spawned item to be directly above the UMG image it was dropped over. However I doubt this is the best way to do it. If there is a better way to spawn a paper actor directly over a UMG widget I would love to hear about it.